# SharePoint Online Modern Page Layout Column Size

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I am trying to make three column page layout and I want middle column to be bigger than other two. How it is possible.

Do we have to add anything into spfx web part or is there other way !!

Comment: Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, there is currently no OOTB method to modify the height and width of the column.

Here's a user voice that's been proposed:

[Allow changing the width of columns when adding sections to a Modern Page](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33079264-allow-changing-the-width-of-columns-when-adding-se)

If you are in desperate need of this requirement, you can write custom CSS in modern pages, which is not a good suggestion.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Please note: Microsoft provides third-party contact information to help you find technical support. This contact information may change without notice. Microsoft does not guarantee the accuracy of this third-party contact information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Still I am not convince with the approach because my all web parts are in  **React**. and it should be in provision spfx to handle it.

Comment: You can view the information on the user voice page, and once this feature is up-to-date, SharePoint User Voice Admin will reply below.
In addition, you can also vote this UserVoice and keep monitoring it. The high votes may let the related team pay more attention to this.Thank you for your understanding.